# Track Changes between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to track what changed between two dataframes:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'A':['a1','Changed','a3','Deleted'],'B':['b2','b2','b3','Deleted']})
df2 = DataFrame({'A':['a1','a2','a3','Added'],'B':['b2','b2','Changed','Added']})
```

df1:

```
    A      B       df1
0   a1      b2      1
1   Changed b2      1
2   a3      b3      1
3   Deleted Deleted 1
```

df2:

```
    A       B      df2
0   a1      b2      1
1   a2      b2      1
2   a3      Changed 1
3   Added   Added   1
```

Desired Output:

```
A        B         df1  df2 Diff    Delta
Added    Added      0   1   -1      Added
Changed  b2         1   0    1      Changed
a2       b2         0   1   -1      Added
a3       Changed    1   0    1      Changed
Deleted  Deleted    1   0    1      Deleted
```

Delas that need to be tracked are: Any changes to existing records, additions, deletions.

I have tried initializing the presence of a row in each data frame with 1 and doing an outer merge, getting the Difference between 'df1' and 'df2' and using all the diff to design a logic that can assign changes, deletions, additions to a data frame. For example, Where diff == -1, it means that 'df1' = 0 and 'df2' = 1 implying that it was an addition.

```
df1['df1'] = 1
df2['df2'] = 1
df = pandas.merge(df1,df2,on=['A','B'],how='outer')
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df['Diff'] = df['df1'] - df['df2']
df['Delta'] = numpy.nan
df.loc[df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)&df['Diff']!=0,'Delta'] ='Changed'
df.loc[(df['Delta'].isnull())&(df['Diff']== (-1)),'Delta'] = 'Added'
df.loc[(df['Delta'].isnull())&(df['Diff']== (1)),'Delta'] = 'Deleted'
print df.loc[df['Delta'].notnull()].drop_duplicates(subset='A')
```

This gives me:

[image]
I have added the column 'Correct_Delta' indicates what needs to be the correct output column 'Delta'. I have an issue with the highlighted cells.

PS: column 'A' will always be unique and 'A' and 'B' will have many to one relationship in some cases  and one to one relationship in some cases.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: This is very confusing.  It would probably serve you to take more time to explain what is actually being checked and what constitutes changes.  Where you say "I have tried this" doesn't do a good job describing what you mean to do.

Comment: Do my latest edits serve well to explain the 'tried this:'? @piRSquared

Comment: Can you post how you want your desired output to be? So you want `B` column to have `changed` instead of `b3`? `df.loc[df.delta.notnull()].drop_duplicates("A",keep='last')`?

Comment: You are right @SaiKumar

Comment: Got one part of the answer. Yes, thank you!. Had overlooked it.